# phase space partition and symbolic dynamics

Tags: dynamical-systems

I want to learn the basic theory of phase space partition and symbolic dynamics, can you point to any recent thesis and books containing a good exposition ? Thanks!

Comment: Broad questions like this may have difficulty attracting responses.  Perhaps a brief summary of your interest in the topics (systems of ordinary differential equations?) would help to narrow the question for interested Readers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can try the large book by Katok and Hasselblatt ("Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems"), they have everything inside.